# Focus engine tvOS

Tags: ios, tvos

I have searched on google and found a couple of example for `tvOS` focus engine. does this `tvOS` feature work on `iPhone` or `iPad`?

Can a user interact with touch instead of apple remote on `iPhone` or `iPad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The tvOS focus engine **only** works for tvOS devices, like the Apple TV, and the feature **does not** work for iPhones or iPads.
2. Yes, the user interacts using touch on iPhone and iPad (iOS devices) instead of the Apple remote.

From the [App Programming Guide for tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html)

> On iOS devices, a user interacts directly with the touchscreen. On Apple TV, a remote is used to control the interface indirectly.